# array of rows to table react js / javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Is there a way I can easily map an array of rows to a table in react js / javascript? My data looks like this:

```
    rows: [['10kg', '12.5', '1.25', '8'], 
['25kg', '28.75', '1.15', '6'], 
['50kg', '50', '1.0', '5'], 
['100kg', '100', '1.0', '3'], 
['250kg', '250', '1.0', '5'], 
['500kg', '500', '1.0', '5'], 
['1liter', '1000', '1.0', '5']]

"labels": [
        "Weight",
        "Price",
        "Price Per",
        "Amount"

      ],
```

In python there are tables where I can set the columns then loop through the array and add the row through the array item. Is there something like this for javascript / reactjs?

Comment: You want to create a table with that ? Do you use a component library like ant-design or other ?

Comment: Do you want to output an html table? If so, the answer is "yes". This is indeed something you can do with reactjs or with plain javascript.

Comment: @azro yes, right now I am using material ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the data as list to objects:

```js
let rows = [['10kg', '12.5', '1.25', '8'], 
  ['25kg', '28.75', '1.15', '6'], 
  ['50kg', '50', '1.0', '5'], 
  ['100kg', '100', '1.0', '3'], 
  ['250kg', '250', '1.0', '5'], 
  ['500kg', '500', '1.0', '5'], 
  ['1liter', '1000', '1.0', '5']];

let labels = ["Weight","Price","Price Per","Amount"];

let values = rows.map((row, idx) => {
  let d = {id: idx};
  row.forEach((c, i) => d[labels[i]] = c);
  return d;
});

console.log(values)

let columns = labels.map(l => ({field: l, width: 150}));

console.log(columns);
```

Then render with a [`DataGrid`](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/)

```
return <DataGrid rows={values} columns={columns}/>
```

Comment: Is there a way to automatically create an ID in the mapping done above? I seem to be having a problem where MaterialUI/data grid requires each row to have a unique id. This is the error I'm getting in my program: Error: MUI: The data grid component requires all rows to have a unique id property.
A row was provided without id in the rows prop:
{"Weight":"20 kg","Price":"69.99","Price Per":"3.499"}

Comment: @BRICKMANE see my edit on values construction, it should be enough